# What does "20/ln(2)" mean in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic

I am trying to understand Logistic Regression in relation to credit scoring model. I wish to understand the significance of "20/ln(2)" in logistic regression. Why and how is it used?

Comment: Could you please give a www link how 20/ln(2) is applied? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a simple transformation (on a linear scale) http://bit.ly/klhGCr

Answer (score 14):

This is a common scaling factor used for credit scoring models built with logistic regression.

The interpretation of the dependent variable in logistic regression is as **log odds**, but in credit scoring, we like to deal in points, thus a scaling factor is applied to the log odds to convert to the point system.

A widely used convention in credit scoring is the concept of "**Points to Double the Odds**" (often abbreviated PDO), and this is the source of the $\ln (2)$ in the question.  For example, how many points does the score change if the odds increase from 100:1 to 200:1.

A common default value for PDO is 20, because it produces credit score ranges that people tend to like.

So, the interpretation of the $20/\ln(2)$ is that for a 20-point increase in score, the odds double.

Answer (score 5):

Typically in credit scoring one would choose a baseline score e.g. 600. We assign a certain meaning to 600 for example, 600 means the good bad odd is 30:1 (where bad typically means a default, the default definition is typically 90 days past payment due on the loan, however the bad definition can vary). Typically they also define that a 20 point jump means doubling of odds, for example 620 means the good bad odd if 60:1 and 640 is 120:1 etc. This definition comes from logistic regression.

If we fit a logistic regression model the model being fitted is this

$$\log(p/(1-p)) = a + b_1d_1 + \cdots + b_n  d_n$$

where $a$ and $b_i$ are parameter estimates and $p$ is the probability of good $d_i$ are your raw data (explanatory variables). The LHS is the log good bad odds. To conform to the above mentioned standard (i.e. 600 is 30:1 and 620 is 60:1) we scale the RHS using $c$ and $d$ found by solving these simultaneous equations

$$600 = c\log(30/1) + d = c + d(a + b_1d_1 + \cdots + b_n  d_n)$$
$$620 = c\log(60/1) + d = c + d(a + b_1d_1 + \cdots + b_n d_n)$$

you will get $c = 20/\log(2)$. Hence scaling the RHS by $c$ and $d$ will give you the scores you want. Hence we see that $20/\log(2)$ is just to achieve the 20 points to double odds mantra.

Answer (score 0):

As for me all this theory wasn't that obvious I provide code with formulas to explain how all the "definitions" are translated into the resulting score.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame()

df['fc']=[206, 205, 200, 220, 230, 235, 236, 240,250]
df['cat']=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,0]
df['good']=[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,1]

train=df[['fc','cat']]
y=df['good']

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf=LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, solver='lbfgs')
clf=clf.fit(train, y)

coefficients = np.append (clf.intercept_, clf.coef_)
print('Coefficients', coefficients)        

#Option 1: Predict proba
test=pd.DataFrame (np.array([200,1]).reshape(1,2))       
y_pred=clf.predict_proba(test)[:,1]
print('Predict proba: ' ,y_pred)

#Option 2: Calculate Probability
ln_odds=sum(np.multiply(coefficients,np.array([1,200,1]))) # sum(coefficients*values)=ln(odds)
odds=np.exp(ln_odds)
prob_good=odds/(1+odds)
print('Resulting probablity: ', prob_good)

#score from Siddiqi
pdo=20
factor=pdo/np.log(2)
offset=200

score1=offset+factor*np.log(1) #p_bad=0.5,   bad=good > odds=1
score2=offset+factor*np.log(2) #p_bad=0,3(3) good=2 bad=1 
score3=offset+factor*np.log(4) #p_bad=0,2    good=4 bad=1 
print(f'Difference 2 and 1: {score2-score1} \nDifference 3 and 2: {score3-score2}'  )

'''To calculate score from logregression '''
#NB! in regression target 1 should be set to good as in Siddiqi odds are 100:1 meaning 100 good and 1 bad 
score=offset-factor*sum(np.multiply(coefficients,np.array([1,200,1])))
print(f'Score from regression:  {round(score,0)}')

#score from probability
score=offset+factor*np.log(prob_good/(1-prob_good))
print(f'Score from probability:  {round(score,0)}')
```