# How to properly define the score function from prediction of GLM

Tags: r, logistic

I am reading a book, which states how to calculate the `Score function` from the prediction of the `glm()` function of `R`.

The statement goes as below -

*Our aim is to define a new scale with anchor set at 660 points and log-odds doubling each 40 points. A 72:1 odds ratio is identified in line with credit bureau common practice.*

And finally they define the score function as -

```
scaled_score <- function(logit, odds, offset = 500, pdo = 20)
{
b = pdo/log(2)
a = offset - b*log(odds)
round(a + b*log((1-logit)/logit))
}
```

It appears that :

`logit` -> the prediction from the `glm()` function in `R` using `predict()` function

`odds` -> `72` (hard-coded)

I failed to understand what is the exact purpose of this `scaled_score()` function? Why they define the `scaled_score()` in the above way i.e. what do the variables `a,b` etc. signify?

Any insight will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms $a$ and $b$ are derived by solving a system of equations. For example, if 20 points doubles the odds and the base score is 660, then you can set up two equations. See this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10092/what-does-20-ln2-mean-in-logistic-regression#:%7E:text=Typically%20they%20also%20define%20that,definition%20comes%20from%20logistic%20regression.&text=you%20will%20get%20c%3D20,you%20the%20scores%20you%20want.).